# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting for AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Java 8

Tags: java, encryption, java-8, encryption-symmetric

I was using Cipher for encryption of String in my project.It was working fine with Java 7 but when I need to update the java version to Java 8,It is throwing error:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting

I am using AES algorithim and java 1.8.0_152 in my project.Below is the line which is throwing exception

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

I checked the Oracle docs and seems this algorithim doesn't have restriction and should support.

Please suggest where it is going wrong?

Comment: It was working fine with Java 8 but fails with Java 8?

Comment: My Bad !!! It was working fine with Java 7 and failing in Java 8

Comment: Try with PKCS7 padding instead.  It is effectively the same as PKCS5.

Comment: @rossum: in the real world, and in BouncyCastle, but not in Oracle/OpenJDK which uses only the name PKCS5Padding not the name PKCS7Padding. kinnu: yes this should work. Are there other crypto operations in this program and do they work? Has JRE/lib/security/java.security been modified? What does `for(Provider p: Security.getProviders()) System.out.println(p.getName());` show?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 No modification has been done in  JRE/lib/security/java.security .I suspect if this is a build path issue but I had made sure the  build contains JRE 8.Any suggestions on this

Comment: No, this is not build path. Unlike other Java library functions, JCE (by design) doesn't require the providers to even be present at compile time, only the (fixed) facade. It could be runtime, but shouldn't. Did you look at the provider list at the point fo the problem, and is `SunJCE` in it? What if you use the two-arg form `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE")`? Whose build or package of 8_152 is this (Oracle, a Linux distro, your coworker Fred)?